# Android: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a Strange error happening on my App on Android Market.
A user said to me that when he try to open my Application, it crashes.
Look at this error:

Anyone have knows this error?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:77)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:351)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:189)
at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:148)
at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:112)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1578)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7198)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error is happening because you are using an index number within your code that is greater than the amount of objects in your array list. Paste some code because thats can be said without it.

Comment: I know. But this error is so confuse, because didn't say anything. I just have a ArrayAdapter...
String[] opcoesGetUsuario = {" ", "Endereço Origem", "Endereço Destino"};

  aSpinnerGetUsuario = new
  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
  opcoesGetUsuario);
  spnPos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnPosUsuario);
  spnPos.setAdapter(aSpinnerGetUsuario);  
        spncidades = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCidades);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the arraylist values out of its values. That's the reason for this error. Post your codings so that we can find what.s the problem exactly.And the best practise is to use for loops. Try using this and hope your problem resolves with this. Else post the code

Answer (score 0):

check setSelection value in spinner